# How to translate a basic math formula into use in a Rails App - where to put it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Thanks to anyone sparing a bit of their time in advance, & apologies as I'm sure this is a frustratingly basic thing to solve.

How would I apply a formula like:

```
total_score = start_score + sum(per_game_scores)/no_of_games - (time/some_value);
```

...to amend a value in a rails app, for each iteration of `per_game_score`?

Say, for example, this is a fantasy football scenario. I'd like to be able to submit a form after each game with the player's `per_game_score` & have the `total_score` stat update accordingly...

Being very new to Rails, I know the basics of all of this process- except where to store the formula, how to access it on form submission & how to ensure it's executed to keep `total_score` value current.

Thanks again for any help, am already very impressed with the community on here in my short time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sort of thing might work well as a method on the player. I'm assuming you have a `Player` model, and that it `has_many :games`

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games

  before_save :update_total_score

  def update_total_score
    self.total_score = start_score + games.average(:score) - time/some_value
  end
end
```

Then you can hook it up with `before_save` callbacks:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player

  before_save :update_player_total_score

  private

  def update_player_total_score
    player.update_total_score
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this Andy! You're absolutely right, this works great! Do you have any suggestions for how to make the 'game' form the first thing seen at login after game is completed? Triggered by the date/time I guess...? Either way, thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Basically you could have a `latest` scope in your `Game` model and redirect to the `show` action for `Game.latest` after login. But if you need more than that brief tip then it would be better as a separate question :)